# Can JavaScript variables be easily modified maliciously?

Tags: javascript, security

I am setting up a quiz that uses boolean variables for correct/incorrect and then passes those variable values to a PHP script via Ajax for processing and storing in a database.

How easily could someone override the values set by my code with after finding the var names with "view source"?

Comment: They wouldn't even need to modify those variables, they could post whatever they wanted.

Comment: It depends on how it's done.  You would need to provide code for us to tell you how secure it is.  AJAX polls can be done securely just like non-AJAX polls, and vice-versa.

Comment: Wouldn't they just need to view-source to find out what the correct answers are, and then complete the quiz normally using those answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They can do it easily using Chrome/Firebug Console by issuing a Javascript command over there like

```
var your_var_name = 60;
```

You must have backend synchronization also to prevent this.

Comment: Funny, `your-var-name` is an invalid identifier in JavaScript. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

You should send the answers to the server and let the server grade the quiz.

Comment: You cannot grade on the client side and send the grade to the server.  You have to do as @rpflo suggested and send the answers to the server and let the scoring happen there.  It is the only way to prevent someone from manipulating the results.

Answer (score 0):

for testing purpose you can use firefox add on firebug or chrome's developer tool kit.  Change your javascript variable using inspect element and than perform action of button which posts your data.  On server side you should make sure that posted variable must be any of variable that is in option of answer of that question.